# Is there a platform porting guide for Chilli Source?

Tags: open-source, game-engine, porting

I have been planning to start porting Chilli Source to Linux but haven't found clear info on what needs to be done to port Chilli Source to a new platform.

Is there a guide for it explaining how to do it or where to look?
-Where the platform specific implementations get "selected" in the code?
-What are the bare minimum systems that a platform needs to implement and the interface they must implement?
-How to add an extra target to the project generator?
-What needs to be pre-compiled as a library and where to place them?

Basically a guide possibly with one of the existing platforms as an example would be fantastic. If not just some highlights as to where in the git repo to look for answers would be welcomed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A full tutorial describing how to port the engine to other platforms is a bit beyond the scope of what can be provided here, however I can give a quick overview.

A platform backend essentially consists of:

- The entry point to the application
- Window creation
- OpenGL context creation
- An implementation of each platform specific system.

The Windows backend is a pretty good example of this: you can see the entry point to the engine in `Main.cpp` and the window/context creation (using SFML) in `SFMLWindow.cpp`.

Platform specific systems are declared abstract, requiring each platform backend to implement their own version of it. All systems are created via the Create() factory method, using the creation of the platform specific concrete system is hidden from the user. A nice clean example of this is the `DialogueBoxSystem`.

Only default systems require implementation on every platform - those that are created in `Application::CreateDefaultSystems()`. Current, this would require implementation of:

- `PlatformSystem`
- `Device`
- `Screen`
- `FileSystem`
- `DialogueBoxSystem`
- `Keyboard` (Only required on systems which have hardware keyboards)
- `PointerSystem`
- `DeviceButtonSystem`
- `TextEntry`

The `Create()` factory method should return `nullptr` on any platform which doesn't implement the system.

Finally, you'll need to build the CSBase library for the new platform - this provides all of the third party code used by the engine: libPng, rapidxml, etc.

Hopefully that should be enough to point you in the right direction. It's also worth checking out Fzort's fork of CS which he has had running on linux: https://github.com/fzort/ChilliSource